# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I encounter this error when I want to import a package:

‍‍‍SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

import:

```
import inquirer from 'inquirer';
```

help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
     "type": "module",
```

to you package.json file